# anaconda could not find my already installed package

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install doconce through the clone: https://github.com/hplgit/doconce

using: `sudo python setup.py install`

This installs successfully and `which doconce` returns

```
> /usr/local/bin/doconce.
```

The problem is that I have anaconda along with regular installation of python. `which python` returns:

```
>/home/sohail/anaconda/bin/python
```

Now when I try to run test.verify from /test, it says:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.verify", line 13, in <module>
  import commands, os, sys, re, doconce.common, time
  ImportError: No module named doconce.common
```

As a second test, I created a do.txt file(doconce file) and when I try to convert it to latex, for example it says:

```
> ImportError: No module named mistune
```

Though the package python package mistune is already installed, as shown by `locate mistune` which returns:

```
> /home/sohail/anaconda/conda-meta/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0.json
> /home/sohail/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistune-0.5.1-py2.7.egg-info
> /home/sohail/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistune.py
> /home/sohail/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistune.pyc
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/info
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/lib
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/info/files
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/info/index.json
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/info/meta
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/info/requires
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/lib/python2.7
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistune-0.5.1-py2.7.egg-info
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistune.py
> /home/sohail/anaconda/pkgs/mistune-0.5.1-py27_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mistune.pyc
```

I have certain idea about the problem that is when I run some python code, the python from anaconda is used but the when I try to run tests or .do.txt files(doconce files) it looks for my python compilier outside anaconda, since doconce is not installed inside anaconda or as a part of anaconda which is the problem. 
So how can I make this work, in summary how can I include doconce to anaconda???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doconce` at pypi is outdated and the authors have little interest in updating due to large dependency base of `doconce`, therefore the use of `conda skeleton` as suggested by @asmeurer in [non_recipe_ananconda_installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545338/how-to-build-a-non-distribution-non-recipe-existent-packages-for-anaconda/29569096#29569096) is of little interest in this particular problem.

I also tried `pip install -e git+https://github.com/hplgit/doconce#egg=doconce` with and without `sudo`. With `sudo` the install is successful but not as a part of anaconda and without `sudo` it leads to a weird error of:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

**This is what that finally works**. First delete all the files installed by `sudo python setup.py install` by using `--record=myfile.txt`.

Now go to the cloned `doconce` repository and do `python setup.py install --prefix=/home/sohail/anaconda/ --record=myfile2.txt`.

This successfully installs `doconce` as a part of anaconda default environment. 
Now you can check that `python` can also accept `doconce` as its module but doing `python -c 'import doconce'` and `sys.modules['doconce']`. Moreover you can also verify the installation by running the tests in `doconce\test`, but keep in mind `doconce` requires too many dependencies. Luckily the owner has made `test_mintest.py` to verify the minimal installation of `doconce`.

In the last you can check `conda list | grep doconce` to verify that `doconce` is indeed a package now part of anaconda.

This procedure was tested to install [doconce](https://github.com/hplgit/doconce) and [logg-publish](https://bitbucket.org/logg/publish) as a part of anaconda.

Comment: You can still build a conda recipe manually. `conda skeleton` is just there to make building a recipe easier for those packages that are on PyPI.

Comment: @asmeurer. Agree. In present situation, does recipe is necessary condition to upload doconce to binstar.org?

Comment: If you want to create a conda package you will need to build a recipe. Take a look at the example recipes at https://github.com/conda/conda-recipes/ and the recipe documentation at http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build.html.

Comment: @asmeurer. Its not the conda package I want. I just want a way to upload my doconce; which is already installed as a conda package,  to binstar.org. By your last answer, should I infer that I need to start from scratch(making recipe) to be able to upload to binstar.org? which definitely is a weird solution.

Comment: Where did you get doconce as a conda package? If you have a conda package for it already, you can use `binstar upload` to upload it to binstar.

Comment: @asmeurer Isn't doconce installed as a conda package in my system??? What package type should be used to upload doconce via `binstar upload`, since just doing `binstar upload doconce` leads to `binstar error`. The error is:`Could not detect package type of file 'doconce' please specify package type with option --package-type `

Comment: How did you install doconce?

Comment: If you installed it using setup.py then you didn't build a conda package. If you want to build a conda package (which is what you need to do if you want to upload it to binstar), you need to write a conda recipe.

Comment: @asmeurer. Thanks for clearing it up but do you not think, as a `conda` developer,  the implementation of reverse isn't that difficult, so that one should be able to build the installed packages without making a recipe.

Comment: If you want, you can take a look at the `conda package` command, which does something similar to this.