# How to build a non-distribution, non-recipe existent packages for anaconda

Tags: build, anaconda

This question is rather a paraphrase of not yet attended question: [anaconda could not find my already installed package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508309/anaconda-could-not-find-my-already-installed-package)

I want to build doconce(https://github.com/hplgit/doconce) as a part of anaconda when no recipe for that repository is available.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For packages on PyPI, the easiest way is to use the `conda skeleton pypi` command, like

```
conda skeleton pypi doconce
```

This will create a recipe for doconce from the metadata on PyPI, which you can then build with

```
conda build doconce
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was experimenting with different packages from pypi and have also looked at the issue you raised at `github/conda` that all pypi packages may not work. Any general way of finding it out before tying `conda skeleton pypi *`??

Comment: Does the developer have to take some extra measure for his pypi package to be accepted by `conda skeleton`?

Comment: additionally do they have any plans of supporting `CTAN` for `conda skeleton` on pattern of `pypi, cpan, cran`?

Comment: No one has requested CTAN support but if there is enough interest it can be added.

Comment: Would you please comment on the soundness of my solution at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508309/anaconda-could-not-find-my-already-installed-package/29689993#29689993